# pgfplotstable error on read

Tags: siunitx, pgfplotstable

I have a Problem with a `\pgfplotstableread` command. I m always getting the output:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'VasconcelosEtAl2012' as a floating point number, sorry. 
The unreadable part was near 'VasconcelosEtAl2012'.. }
```

My intention is to use a table (inline or as csv) with some rows filled with data to process with `biber`(Citecommands) or `siunitx` (Angles for coordinates).

So here is a MWE as I understand it:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxbibnames=25, maxcitenames=2,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    %some bib-libraries
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[begin table=\begin{longtable},end table=\end{longtable},
header=true, col sep=comma, row sep=newline,
%0
columns/0/.style={ string replace*={##1}{\textcite{##1}}, column name {Quelle1}, string type,  column type =l},
%1
columns/1/.style={column name={Ort}, verb string type, column type = l},
%2
columns/2/.style={column name={Longitude}, string replace*={##1}{\ang{##1}},string type, column type=r},
%3
columns/3/.style={column name={Latitude},string replace*={##1}{\ang{##1}}, string type, column type=r},
%4
columns/4/.style={column name ={Wert}, column type=r, dec sep align,fixed,precision=2},
%5
columns/5/.style={column name={[Einheit]}, replace string*{##1}{$##1$}, string type},
%6
columns/6/.style={column name=Beschreibung, verb string type, column type=l},
%7
columns/7/.style={column name={$\rho [kg/m^3]$}, column type=r, dec sep align,fixed,precision=2},
%8
columns/8/.style={column name={Quelle $\rho$}, string replace*={##1}{\textcite{##1}}, string type, column type=l},
%9
columns/9/.style={column name={$l$}, precision=2, column type=r},    
%10
columns/10/.style={column name={NAI [$m^3\cdot ha^{-1}$]}, dec sep align,fixed,precision=2, column type=r},
%11
columns/11/.style={column name={Spezien}, string replace*{##1}{\textit{##1}}, string type},
]{
Autor,Ort,Longitude,Latitude,Wert,Einheit,Beschreibung,Dichte,DQuelle,la,NAI,Baumarten
VasconcelosEtAl2012,Brasilien ,-1;19;0,+47;57;0,14.45,$Mg / ha \cdot year$,ANPP,0.704,NogueiraEtAl2005,0.5,4.928,-
BernierEtAl2007,Chibougamau Quebec,+49;41;31.2,+74;25;55.2,2090,$kg /ha \cdot yr$, ANPP Stems,0.45,AseevaEtAl2014,,4.644444444,Picea mariana  (Black Spruce) 
}
\end{landscape}%
\end{document}`
```

In the original file I'm using BiBLaTeX, but this replacement is working in another table, where I just had keys in a row, that's why I guess it has something to do with the `siunitx` package or I don't see a missing bracket.

And yes the table is too wide for standard formats, but this is another problem.

### ----------

So most of the problems are solved, but here is the next:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxbibnames=25,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%some bib styles and files
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[begin table=\begin{longtable},end     table=\end{longtable},
header=true, col sep=comma, use comma, row sep=newline,
every head row/.append style={after row=\endhead},
%0
columns/Autor/.style={string replace*={##1}{\textcite{##1}},column name={Quelle}, string type, column type =l},
%1
columns/Ort/.style={column name={Ort}, verb string type, column type = l},
%2
columns/Longitude/.style={column name={Longitude},string replace*={##1}    {\ang{##1}}, string type, column type=r},
%3
columns/Latitude/.style={column name={Latitude},string replace*={##1}{\ang{##1}}  , string type, column type=r},
%4
columns/Wert/.style={column name ={Wert}, column type=r, dec sep align,fixed,precision=2},
%5
columns/Einheit/.style={column name={[Einheit]}, string replace*={##1}{$##1$}, string type},
%6
columns/Beschreibung/.style={column name=Beschreibung,string replace*={##1}{$\mathrm{##1}$}, string type, column type=l},
%7
columns/Dichte/.style={column name={$\rho [kg/m^3]$}, column type=r, dec sep align,fixed,precision=2},
%8
columns/DQuelle/.style={column name={Quelle $\rho$}, string replace*={##1}{\textcite{##1}}, string type, column type=l},
%9
columns/la/.style={column name={$l$}, precision=2, column type=r},
%10
columns/NAI/.style={column name={NAI [$m^3\cdot ha^{-1}$]},fixed,precision=2, column type=r , dec sep align},
%11
columns/Baumarten/.style={column name={Spezien}, string replace*={##1}{\textit{##1}}, string type, column type =l}
]
{
Autor,Ort,Longitude,Latitude,Wert,Einheit,Beschreibung,Dichte,DQuelle,la,NAI,Baumarten
BernierEtAl2007,Groundhog River Ontario,48;13;1.2,82;9;21.6,,,,0.45,AseevaEtAl2014,,,Picea mariana  (BS)
}
\end{landscape}%
\end{document}
```

The output is:

> File ended while scanning use of \pgfutil@in@@.

I guess it has something to do with the "empty cells"... It works with the lines provided in the MWE above, but as soon it start to read those `,,,` it stop working. Is the `empty cell with` usefull here?

Comment: your `row sep` is a newline but you have `%` chars at the end so it can't find the new row.

Comment: yes i gave that already a try, but then it comes to `! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column '' from table '<inli
ne_table>'. Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases)..`

Comment: So because there are more errors you want to keep the `%`s ?

Comment: yes, propably not the best way, but I dont know how to solve that in another way

Comment: it is not a way. You are not able to read the data that way

Comment: Okay, but now it wont parse my citekeys:`'! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'VasconcelosEtAl2012' as a floa
ting point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'VasconcelosEtAl2012'..`even if i wrote string type or as a try verb string type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following fixes mosts of the errors.  You have a number of misspelled keys including a `replace string*` instead of `string replace*` and a `verb string type` instead of `string type`.

There remains some mismatch in the number of columns that I can't track down yet, but I am posting this in the hope that you will be able to get further.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[begin table=\begin{longtable},end table=\end{longtable},
header=true, col sep=comma, use comma, row sep=newline,
every head row/.append style={after row=\endhead},
%0
columns/Autor/.style={string replace*={##1}{\textcite{##1}},column name={Quelle}, string type, column type =l},
%1
columns/Ort/.style={column name={Ort}, verb string type, column type = l},
%2
columns/Longitude/.style={column name={Longitude},string replace*={##1}{\ang{##1}}, string type, column type=r},
%3
columns/Latitude/.style={column name={Latitude},string replace*={##1}{\ang{##1}}  , string type, column type=r},
%4
columns/Wert/.style={column name ={Wert}, column type=r, dec sep align,fixed,precision=2},
%5
columns/Einheit/.style={column name={[Einheit]}, string replace*={##1}{$##1$}, string type},
%6
columns/Beschreibung/.style={column name=Beschreibung, verb string type, column type=l},
%7
columns/Dichte/.style={column name={$\rho [kg/m^3]$}, column type=r, dec sep align,fixed,precision=2},
%8
columns/DQuelle/.style={column name={Quelle $\rho$}, string replace*={##1}{\textcite{##1}}, string type, column type=l},
%9
columns/la/.style={column name={$l$}, precision=2, column type=r},
%10
columns/NAI/.style={column name={NAI [$m^3\cdot ha^{-1}$]}, dec sep align,fixed,precision=2, column type=r},
%11
columns/Baumarten/.style={column name={Spezien}, string replace*={##1}{\textit{##1}}, string type}
]{
Autor,Ort,Longitude,Latitude,Wert,Einheit,Beschreibung,Dichte,DQuelle,la,NAI,Baumarten
VasconcelosEtAl2012,Brasilien ,-1;19;0,+47;57;0,14.45,Mg / ha \cdot year,ANPP,0.704,NogueiraEtAl2005,0.5,4.928,-
BernierEtAl2007,Chibougamau Quebec,+49;41;31.2,+74;25;55.2,2090,kg /ha \cdot yr,ANPP Stems,0.45,AseevaEtAl2014,0,4.644444444,Picea mariana  (Black Spruce)
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes thanks, now I have this this mismatch in column number too. I will ask again if I need to...

Comment: the mismatch seems to be generated by the `dec sep align` key, I've put it at the end, and that's working right now

Comment: Indeed, placing `dec sep align` after the `column type` key seems to be the crucial ordering.